# send with CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS file located on other server

Tags: php

is possible to send with CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS a source file that isn't located on the server where is running my script?? 
So i can send a file to a server throw an url and not a dir path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You need to retrieve the file first and save it locally.